# ADB fails to start "cannot bind 'tcp:5037'" after updating to Yosemite MAC

Tags: macos, shell, adb, osx-yosemite

After I upgraded to Yosemite and upgraded to Xcode 7.1 I cannot start the adb server. Both of which I don't see why they would affect adb. When I type `adb devices` or `adb start-server` in the terminal I get:

```
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

- There are no adb processes running that I can see in activity monitor.
- I've checked with `lsof -i tcp:5037` that there are running processes on port 5037.
- I have the latest Android SDK.
- I have checked that my `.bashrc` loads the correct Android SDK and adb.
- I've tried to `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server` several times, but when I run start-server I get the error message that I cannot bind tcp:5037.
- I've tried deleting .android folder and unplugging/plugging in my android phone, toggling on/off USB-debugging and revoking debugging authorizations.
- Android studio cannot start adb anymore as well.
- I've tried restarting the computer.
- I'm not running Genymotion.

None of the above worked, and I'm about to give up. I've checked every stackoverflow thread about this issue and none of the mentioned fixes have worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

Success.

Oddly enough, adb worked again after I upgraded Yosemite to El Capitan (10.11).